# derivative and integral as opposite operations

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider:

$$\lim_{y\to\infty} \left( \int_0^y f(t)dt \right)'  = \lim_{y\to\infty} f(y)$$

So the integral and the derivative cancel each other, but why is it happened to be that it equals to the RHS?

Note: We've learned only about Riemann integral.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus states exactly that (under some conditions on $f$) the function  $y\mapsto \int_0^y f(t)\,dt$ is differentiable, with derivative $f(y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}{\int_0^x{f(t})\,dt}=f(x)  $$

This is a simplification of the general form of the Leibniz integral rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}{\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}{f(x,t})\,dt}=f(x,b(x)).b'(x)-f(a,x(a)).a'(x)+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}{f_x(x,t})\,dt$$

The simplifications occurs, because the derivative of the upper limit equals to 1, the negative part equals to $0$ (since $a(x)=0$) and the integral equals to $0$ to since $f(t)$ it's not a function of $x$.

Comment: The first equation you wrote is wrong: $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^\infty f(t)dt$$ is zero, because the expression $\int_0^\infty f(t)dt$ does not depand od $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your equality is the direct consequence of the fact that $$\left(\int_0^y f(t)dt\right)'= f(y),$$

a well known fact that holds for all $y\in [0,b)$ if $f$ is continuous on some $[0,b)$ (in fact, this is true even a slighlty larger class of functions).